# Gave up waiting for root file system device, in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, brightness

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell XPS 15 laptop. I was working fine until yesterday. After a system update, I cannot log in to Ubuntu using normal mode. This is the error I am getting:

> Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
>
> -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
>     - Check rootdelay=(did the system wait long enough?)
>   -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
>   ALERT! UUID=22f93100-9860-44b7-8086-51b4404d499d does not exist. Dropping to a shell
>
> BusyBox v1.27 2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built in shell (ash)
>   Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
>
> (initramfs)

Ubuntu is opening in recovery mode. But there I cannot change the display brightness. In fact,when I did this to check the driver:
ls /system/class/backlight

I found none.

Is there any way I can recover Ubuntu without reinstalling? I have many software's installed and I don't want to loose them now.

Thank you,
Arka

Comment: Try `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 3):

if you see "ALERT! UUID=22f93100-9860-44b7-8086-51b4404d499d does not exist. Dropping to a shell"

and you are not aware of wrong disc definition - you might be fooled by GRUB.

Interrupt GRUB when offering the choices. So

when the GRUB boot options appear do press **e for edit**.

Check everything properly.

In my case (migrated image):

There you may first find perfectly right entries like UUID=[here-comes-your-accurate-value]. And further down 
an entry like 
root=UUID=some-weird-stuff-comes-here.

This is the **fuckup in my case: a wrong root partition definition by GRUB.**

You may **just enter the proper value as simple /dev/sda1 or /dev/nvme2p3p4pblablabla notation instead** of complicated UUID.

(UUID can be found by typing in CLI:

ls -latr /dev/disk/by-uuid/

which can be done with a DVD/stick external boot beforehand).

Of course there are issues with sda and hda and differernt numbering every time you boot (modern times are soooo cooool :-( ) and complicated partitions may use a different root setup. But you have to start somewhere ....

Works 4 me ;-)

When you booted successfully fix the underlying issue in grub config.

My opinion: 
While Lilo ws straight GRUB is back-stabbing.

Comment: Worked with Linux Mint 19.3 xfce 32 bit

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have `cryptsetup` installed on your system, it might have been removed by running `apt-get autoremove`. [More info](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-meta/+bug/1801629).

Comment: Actually that was it for me! Thanks!!! :)