# Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't boot

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04

A few hours ago I installed C# compiler from the terminal in Ubuntu 22.04. Some seconds later the screen froze. Input devices were not working. Only the power button still worked. I turned it off and turned it on again, but it turned out like this.

[image]

Comment: Please check your question; your Ubuntu 22.04 boots to "*The image you are requesting does not exist, or is no longer available.  imgur.com*" ?   Before you used the power button, did you try a clean shutdown using SysRq commands?  By using an unclean shutdown I'd suggest booting *live* media and performing file-system checks, also I'd suggest providing package details of how you installed C#, and clarify if you're using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop etc.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a potential duplicate of multiple questions on the Ubuntu and Unix forums, and the most common issues seem to be incorrect mounting options in `/etc/fstab`, drive corruption, or incorrect BIOS settings. For troubleshooting steps, please refer to the following posts:

1. [UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001351/uuid-xxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)
2. [ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516217/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)
3. [Gave up waiting for root file system device, in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099832/gave-up-waiting-for-root-file-system-device-in-ubuntu-18-04)
4. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2479761

Hope this helps!