# gave up waiting for root file system device Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04

I had spent three days trying to fix this issue.
I tried to follow these solutions. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099832/gave-up-waiting-for-root-file-system-device-in-ubuntu-18-04) and others but I could not fix this issue.

Some information about issue:

```
(initramfs) exit

Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:

Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! UUID=C025f430-2b2f-40ec-b334-da8e827a9a51 does not exist. Dropping

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

The output the help is.

(initramfs) help

Built-in commands:

: [ alias break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec exit export false getopts hash help history let local printf pwd read readonly return set shift test times trap true type ulimit umask unalias unset wait [ [[ acpid arch ash awk basename blockdev busybox cat chmod chroot chvt clear cmp cp cut date deallocvt deluser devmem df du dumpkmap echo egrep env expr false fbset fgrep find fold fstrim grep gunzip gzip hostname hwclock ifconfig ip kill in loadfont loadkmap is lzop mkdir mkfifo mknod mkswap mktemp modinfo more mount my nuke openvt pidof printf ps pwd readlink reboot reset rm rmdir run-init sed seq setkeycodes sh sleep sort stat static-sh stty switch_root sync tail tee test touch tr true tty umount uname uniq wc wget which yes

The output lsblk is:
sh: lsblk: not found.

The output blkid is:
/dev/sda1: LABEL="REDHWAN" UUID="1438-8EAB" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="03fbda08-01

The output reboot is nothing but it is working when add -f like : reboot -f.
The output sudo is:
sh: lsblk: not found.

The output fsck is:
fsck from util-linux 2.34

The output: cat /proc/cmdline

BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-76-generic root=UUID=c025f430-2b2f-40ec-b334-da8e827a9a51 ro quiet splash.

The output: cat /proc/modules

hid_generic 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc00ef000

uas 28672 0 - Live 0xffffffffc00cc000

usbhid 65536 0 - Live 0xffffffffc013f000 usb_storage 77824 1 uas, Live 0xffffffffc0059000

hid 147456 2 hid_generic, usbhid, Live 0xffffffffc002b000

ahci 45056 0 - Live 0xffffffffc023a000

xhci_pci 24576 0 Live 0xffffffffc024d000

psmouse 176128 0 Live 0xffffffffc025a000

crc32_pclmul 16384 0 Live 0xffffffffc0232000

igc 159744 0 - Live 0xffffffffc01ff000

libahci 45056 1 ahci, Live 0xffffffffc01b6000

xhci_pci_renesas 20480 1 xhci_pci, Live 0xffffffffc01a0000

umi 32768 0 Live Oxffffffffc0073000

video 61440 0 Live 0xffffffffc001b000

The output: ls /dev

vga_arbiter

tty24

fuse

rfkill

tty25 tty26

ptmx

mem

ttyso

null

tty27

ttyS1

port

tty28

ttys2 ttys3

zero

tty29

full

tty30

ttyS4

random

tty31

ttys5

urandom

tty32

ttyS6

kmsg tty

tty33 tty34

ttys7 ttys8

console

tty35

ttys9

ttyo

tty36

ttyS10

VCS

tty37

ttyS11

VCSU

tty38

ttyS12

vcsa

tty39

ttyS13

VCS1 VCSU1

tty40 tty41

ttyS14

ttyS15

Avcsa1

tty42 tty43

ttyS16

ttyl

ttyS17

tty2

tty44

ttyS18

1tty3 tty4

tty45

ttyS19

tty46

ttys20

tty5 tty6

tty47

ttys21

tty48

ttys22

tty7 tty8

tty49

ttys23

tty50 tty51

ttys24

tty9

ttys25

tty52

ttys26

tty11 tty12

tty53

ttys27

tty54

ttys28

tty13

tty55

ttys29

tty14

tty56

ttys30

tty15

tty57 tty58 tty59

ttys31

tty16 tty17

ttyprintk

hpet

tty18

tty60

hurng

tty19

tty61

tpmo

tty20 tty21

tty62

tpmrmo

tty63

100p-control

tty22

snapshot

100p2

loop3

100p4

loop7

dma_heap udmabuf

net

ppp vfio

input

psaux

uinput

rtco

mapper

fbo

mcelog

cpu_dma latency

pts

core

fd

stdin

stdout

stderr

char

rtc

block

bus

ptpo

hidrawo

hidrawi

usb

hidrau

hidraug

bsg

sda

sda1

disk

hidraw4

No output for: cat /etc/fstab

The output: cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg

cat: can't open '/boot/grub/grub.cfg': No such file or directory.
```

Comment: The message "`ALERT! UUID=C025f430-2b2f-40ec-b334-da8e827a9a51 does not exist. Dropping`" means that the disk or partition with that UUID is not visible to your system, and, you tried to boot from it. Either put the disk back online, or edit the "`BOOT_IMAGE=...`  line to point to an actual system.

Comment: @waltinator, Thanks for your comment. How to put the disk back online?

Comment: Please use sudo blkid to list all available partitions and their UUIDs. Edit your original posting to add this information.

Comment: @ubfan1, thanks for your comment. Sadly, sudo, parted, lsblk, vi, nano and fdisk are not working now.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed.

In my case, my PC is recent, and it has a button to press on it in order to restart the BIOS, similar to the router of WIFI.